# Adding Multiple GET verbs gives an error of AmbiguousMatchException

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a WebApi using .NET core 3.1. I'm not sure if this isn't best practice or if there's another way to do this. But, I have a WebApi that will have 3 get verbs. 
1. Get All.
 
2. Get by Id. 
3. Get by a search string.

It work if I have just 2, the get all and get by id but once I had a 3rd, get by string I get an error. Then when I go to test in swagger I get,

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The
>   request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

Code:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
public class ProfessionalLocalController : ControllerBase
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public ProfessionalLocalController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var profLocals = await _unitOfWork.ProfessionalLocalUsers.GetAllAsync();
        return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProfessionalLocalDto>>(profLocals));
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        var localUser = await _unitOfWork.ProfessionalLocalUsers.GetAsync(id);
        if (localUser == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(_mapper.Map<ProfessionalLocalDto>(localUser));
    }

    [HttpGet("{searchText}", Name = "Search")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string searchText)
    {
        var localUsers = await _unitOfWork.ProfessionalLocalUsers.FindAsync(temp => temp.UserID.ToString().Contains(searchText));

        return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProfessionalLocalDto>>(localUsers));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Routes need to be unique when mapped to controller actions.

In this case the routes `[HttpGet("{id}")]` and `[HttpGet("{searchText}", Name = "Search")]` conflict because to both map to the same URI.

```
api/v1/ProfessionalLocal/{some value here}
```

If you want to keep the same URI as before, and allow for the the two action to be distinct, use a route constraint.

```
//GET api/v1/ProfessionalLocal/1234
[HttpGet("{id:int}")] //<-- note the constraint on the id
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id) {
    //...
}
```

So that the above is called only when a valid value is provided. An integer in this case

And consider changing the route template of the search to be more descriptive of what it actually does.

```
//GET api/v1/ProfessionalLocal/search/{search text here}
[HttpGet("search/{searchText}", Name = "Search")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string searchText) {
    //...
}
```

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing it like below:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("users")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var profLocals = await _unitOfWork.ProfessionalLocalUsers.GetAllAsync();
    return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProfessionalLocalDto>>(profLocals));
}

[HttpGet("{id}")]
[Route("users/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
{
    var localUser = await _unitOfWork.ProfessionalLocalUsers.GetAsync(id);
    if (localUser == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(_mapper.Map<ProfessionalLocalDto>(localUser));
}

[HttpGet("{searchText}", Name = "Search")]
[Route("usersbytext/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string searchText)
{
    var localUsers = await _unitOfWork.ProfessionalLocalUsers.FindAsync(temp => temp.UserID.ToString().Contains(searchText));

    return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProfessionalLocalDto>>(localUsers));
}
```

Add a custom route for third one.
The default routing is unable to distinguish [Route("users/{id}")] from [Route("users/{id}")] making it ambigous.

Comment: Using `[HttpGet(<something>)]` will set `<something>` as the route just like `[Route(<something>)]` does. It is not recommended to use _both_ `HttpGet` and `Route` to declare routes.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem recently. My solution was to use the same method for **GetAll** and **Search**. What I did was:

Check for the query parameter, if the query parameter is available, return search results else return all. Please refer to the snippet below.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery]string search)
    {
      if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search)) 
         // return search result
      //return all
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
{
    var profLocals = await _unitOfWork.ProfessionalLocalUsers.GetAllAsync();
    return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProfessionalLocalDto>>(profLocals));
}
```